# Validate View Model Based on Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So everywhere I find that it is better to use view models. It says it will prevent me from 'spegetti code', ok I like that.

I dont think it is a good idea to repeat my validation for each view model, so I found automapper and I am trying this, but it is not working What am I doing wrong?

thanks

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProvider(ProviderNewVM providerVM)
    {
        Provider provider = Mapper.Map<Provider>(providerVM);
        UpdateModel(provider);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Content("ok");    
        }
        return Content("nope");
    }
```

My model:

```
public class Provider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone  { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

my View Model:

```
public class ProviderNewVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to recive a ProviderNewVM class from my view, and convert my model in my controller to Provider class so I can validate with my model validation.

Sory, I am getting an error in  (The model of type 'Controli_web.Models.Provider' could not be updated)

```
UpdateModel(provider);
```

then I changed that line to:

```
TryUpdateModel(provider);
```

and it model is always valid

Comment: What is not working? P.S. You can write spaghetti code whether you have viewmodels or not.

Comment: It is not validating, I will update with my models.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in your AddProvider action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProvider(ProviderNewVM providerVM)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<ProviderNewVM , Provider>();
    Provider provider = Mapper.Map<ProviderNewVM,Provider>(providerVM);
    UpdateModel(provider);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Content("ok");    
    }
    return Content("nope");
}
```

Comment: I did this in my global.asax (Mapper.CreateMap<ProviderNewVM , Provider>();)